# Restart Timer only after the first timer has stopped

Tags: swift, timer

I have created my own timer class named myTimer. I only want to start myTimer again when my first timer has stopped. How do I fix this?

```
class myTimer{
    var timer = Timer()
     var totalTime = 0
    let score = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))

    init()
    {

}
func start(){
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 

  }
```

func stop(){

```
        timer.invalidate()
        totalTime = 0    

}

@objc func timerUpdate() {

        totalTime += 1
        print(totalTime)

    if(totalTime == 10){

        stop()
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: "I only want to start myTimer again when my first timer has stopped" ... You're stopping the timer, but never starting the next one. Do you automatically start the next timer when the first one stops, or are you saying that if you call `start`, you don't want it to start if the previous one is still running.

Comment: BTW, as a fail safe, I'd make sure that `start` does `timer?.invalidate()` before starting a timer. That way you never have two timers running at the same time. Also, I'd personally suggest making the `timer` a `weak` var, so that when it's stopped, it's automatically deallocated for you. There's no need for you to keep a strong reference to it, as the run loop on which it is scheduled will keep a strong reference until it's invalidated.

Comment: Unrelated, by convention, types like `MyTimer` should start with an uppercase letter. Type names (like `struct`, `class`, `enum`, etc.) should always start with uppercase letter. Only variable names, enumeration values, etc., should start with lowercase letter.

Comment: I dont want it to start when the previous timer is running.

Comment: BTW, I think this new code in your revised question is, in several respects, worse than your original code. Obviously, the formatting is hard to read. And `timer` really should be an optional, `Timer?`, not a simple `Timer` that you instantiate as a dummy timer with `var timer = Timer()`. None of this is relevant to the immediate problem (but, then again, neither are your changes to your code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I dont want it to start when the previous timer is running.

You can use a `guard` statement to check that either `timer` is `nil` or that `isValid` is `false`:

```
func start() {
    if timer?.isValid ?? false { return }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: I tried if timer?.isValid ?? false { return } but its still running the next timer even if the previous timer is running. I only want one timer to run and when that timer stop the new should begin.

Comment: I'd suggest printing `timer?.isValid ?? false`. Is that not printing `true` when the timer is running?

Comment: Its true when I print (timer?.isValid ?? false)

Comment: So, if that returns `true`, then that will `return` before it gets to the line scheduling the timer. But you say it's running the next timer. So I wonder if the problem is something else (e.g. not two separate `Timer`, but rather two completely separate `MyTimer` instances). Make sure you have only one instance of `MyTimer`.

Comment: I only create a instance of myTimer every time I press back button in a view controller.  So my goal here is to only create a new instance when the previous is done.  let timer = myTimer() and then timer.start() in back button action.

Comment: I'm inferring that you must be dealing with separate `MyTimer` instances. If that's the case, you could make your `timer` variable a `static`, which means that it will shared across instances of `MyTimer`.